# Twitter card image won't show up

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

**Description of issue:** My card image refuses to show up no matter what I do. All the other meta tag elements like url, title and description show up in the compose tweet window and on the timeline when I post a tweet.

**URL affected:** Here’s the url that’s having issues: https://dasaweb.co/.

**Troubleshooting steps attempted:** I’ve done all the troubleshooting recommended at Card Debugging and the image still doesn’t show up:

- My metatags are formatted properly and show up when I view page
  source. Curl requests output also show my meta tags.
- As far as I can see, my host doesn’t block Twitter’s IP range as all
  the other meta tag elements appear in the card.
- The image file is accessible via the absolute path provided in the meta tag.
- The Card Validator shows the following in the log:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  17 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully
```

- I tested hosting my image file on both http and https pages just in
  the event that contributes to the error in some way.
- The image conforms to the size guidelines. It’s 1200pxx600px, 2:1
  aspect ratio and 336.67kb.

It seems to me like I’m doing everything right. I’m not sure what the issue is.

Comment: It could possibly be because you are using 'property' attributes instead of 'name' attributes in your Twitter meta tags which is what Facebook uses.

Comment: I am not. All my attributes are as they should be.